# How to use multifield search in elasticsearch combining should and must clause

Tags: elasticsearch

This may be a repeted question but I'm not findin' a good solution.

I'm trying to search elasticsearch in order to get documents that contains:

```
- "event":"myevent1"
- "event":"myevent2"
- "event":"myevent3"
```

the documents must not contain all of them in the same document but the result should contain only documents that are only with those types of events.
And this is simple because elasticsearch helps me with the clause `should`
which returns exactly what i want.
But then, I want that all the documents must contain another condition that is I want the field `result.example.example = 200` and this must be in every single document PLUS the document should be 1 of the previously described `"event"`.

So, for example, a document has `"event":"myevent1"` and `result.example.example = 200` another one has `"event":"myevent2"` and `result.example.example = 200` etc etc.

I've tried this configuration:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":{"match":{"operation.result.http_status":200}},
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "event": "bank.account.patch"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "event": "bank.account.add"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "event": "bank.user.patch"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

but is not working 'cause I also get documents that not contain 1 of the should field.

Hope I explained well,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, your query tells ES to look for documents that must have `"operation.result.http_status":200` and to boost those that have a matching event type.

You're looking to combine two `must` queries

- one that matches one of your event types,
- one for your other condition

The `event` clause accepts multiple values and those values are exact matches : you're looking for a [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html).

Try

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match":{"operation.result.http_status":200}},
                {
                    "terms" : {
                        "event" : [
                            "bank.account.patch", 
                            "bank.account.add", 
                            "bank.user.patch"
                         ]
                    }
                }
            ]

        }
    }
}
```